# What is the best way to show the user they have watched a video?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation

I'm created a Rewards site. Users can watch videos to earn points. The problem, users want to skip the entire video to earn their points. Therefore, the mechanism for earning points is based on time viewing the video. Therefore, they could be half way through the video, then have the video timer equal 100%.

### Things I've thought of:

1. Show the % of the video watched in the corner of the video
2. Have a circle and hve it show green once the video is completed
3. Once the timer is over, stop the video and show something similar to this:

[image: #1 Visual Aid]

If the timer finished *during* the video, the button will say: "Continue Watching." Or, if the timer finished *after* the video, the button will say: "Re-watch Video."

In both cases, the user can move on and earn more points because they met the needs for the time requirement.

**What is the most efficient and best way to display this kind of information?**

Comment: So the most users don't want to watch the videos, and the only motivation is to earn the points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important:

Do not stop the video unless it has completed its playing duration. Even if user completes the necessary view time to claim points. This abrupt stop is annoying if I am watching a video of say, 10 minutes, and after the 7th minute. it stop showing me claimed points. I still have 3 minutes of video left.

I would suggest to have a visual indication (for e.g. Button saying "Claim Points) when necessary view time to claim points is completed. But do not stop the Video. Let the video play. Let user explicitly stop the video.

If user clicks on visual indication then you can stop the video and navigate user to the screen you have showcased in the question above.

Also if it is not that important, I would not display progress bar; because I want user to watch the full video(like you have the option for points for completion). When user has completed the said time duration to claim point(s), visual indicator/Toast message can pop up on the video player to grab attention of the viewer.

Comment: I'm going to do this. Interesting take...